# Using JAX-B in Eclipse 4.23 Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to update my Eclipse plugin to Java 17 and Eclipse 4.23 (2022-03).
The plugin used JAX-B in Java 8 which included the required classes, but now i need to change it to separate libraries.

In order to do so i added these to the list of "Required Plug-ins"

> ```
> jakarta.xml.bind
> org.eclipse.persistence.moxy
> ```

Both plugins are readily available in my installation, so that seemed to be the most sensible approach.

It seems that the `javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder` included in jakarta.xml.bind is found and tries to load `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`. But that step fails at JAXBContext.newInstance:

> ```
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been
> found on module path or classpath.
> - with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory]
>     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:232)
>     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:345)
>     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
>     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:147)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
>     at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
>     at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
>     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:230)
>     ... 46 more
> ```

What confuses me greatly about this is that the class JAXBContextFactory can be found if i use `JAXBContext.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBContextFactory.class")` where the class loader is `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader`. But the internal workings of JAXBContext appear to use a different class loader (`org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder`) and that can't find it.

How can i get it to work?

Comment: For clarification: (a) Prior to the upgrade, were you specifically using MOXy as your JAXB implementation? Or have you been using a different implementation (e.g. the Project Metro reference implementation)? Also (b) it sounds like you have a mix of pre-Jakarta and post-Jakarta libraries - the JAXB `jakarta` libs will never refer to `javax` packages (and vice versa).

Comment: @andrewJames no, before i was using the internal jaxb implementation of Java 8. I picked Moxy just because it is already part of Eclipse. Otherwise i would need to supply additional jars. b) You may be right, but i think the main problem is that class loader doesn't find the implementation. And i'm not sure about Jakarta not using javax packages. I will need to look at it tomorrow, but i think the Jakarta.xml.bind plugin contains the javax packages - at least by name.

Comment: You are correct that the `jakarta.xml.bind` binding API _did_ reference `javax` packages back in version 2.3.x of the API. But I believe that was a transitional version. Starting with version 3.0.0, that has no longer been the case - and it references only `jakarta` packages from that point onwards.

Comment: You should be able to build a "pure Jakarta" set-up for JAXB using _only_ these 2 JARs: (1) The API JAR [jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/3.0.1) and (2) An implementation JAR - e.g. the Glassfish (Metro) JAR [jaxb-runtime-3.0.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/3.0.1). If you choose MOXy, then some additional config may be needed (depending on your specific scenario).

Comment: That means i can't use prepared plugins and have to include Jars - 8 of them via transitivity.
It works! So thank you (you might want to writeup your pointers as an answer).
But i would rather have used an existing eclipse plugin, because i can't imagine that there is no way to use JAX-B in eclipse out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It sounds like you can write a more focused/relevant/detailed answer than I can, (using my notes as part of the answer, as needed). If you want to do that, it would get my vote. Otherwise, yes, I will convert my notes to an answer.